# Background color visible over Row colors

Tags: wpf

I have a grid it has a background color, I am then setting row colors, using Border. my grid looks like this:

```
<Grid Background="Red" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="300*"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"  />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Border  Grid.Row="0" Background="#4DC0E4"  />
    <Border  Grid.Row="1" Background="Lime" />
    <Border  Grid.Row="2" Background="Lime" />
    <Border  Grid.Row="3" Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

You can see a horizontal line:

[image: horizontal line]

between the 2nd and 3rd lime Border tag. I have tried using Rectangles instead of Border but it seems to be the same, also if I move the background on the grid itself to the Window it's the same. Is there anyway to get rid of this horizontal line, this line seems to appear if you have two of the same color Border tags next to each other (my page is more complex than this but this is a test representation of the issue).

Comment: Did you try to set the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property to true?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the SnapsToDevicePixels comment, I set that on the Window and it fixed it, many thanks, I have not heard of SnapsToDevicePixels before.